# What are the most common workflows for full stack Node/Express development?

Tags: node.js, express, workflow, web-deployment

I'm a self taught developer and I recently started learning Node.

I've been using Ruby on Rails for a couple of years now, and I learned most of what I know from online courses. The most helpful course I took was one in which I learned the entire process of setting up a development and production server, setting up a database, etc. In this case I was using Cloud9 for development and Heroku for production. I already knew the coding aspect of building a web app, but this course really changed everything for me because I learned how "real" developers work, how to set up a good work flow with a development environment, how to run my code on a real scalable server, etc... Since then I've built a couple of RoR apps on Heroku.

Now I'm learning Node and Express, but I'm not sure what to do with my code. Can I just use Cloud9 and Heroku, the same way I did with RoR? Are there other common services I should know about, similar to how lots of RoR apps use Heroku?

I'm looking for a small push in the right direction - the same one I had when I was learning Rails - to get the ball rolling. Any information will be greatly appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be asking both for [workflow](https://dev.to/tanker/my-javascript-workflow-3po) and [environment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deployment_environment) pointers, so I'll give you a tiny bit of both

#### Env

With `node`, it is perfectly fine to have your dev environment locally and only host your staging and prod environment

If you don't have specific requirements in terms of hosted environment, use what you are already comfortable with:

- [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/) is perfectly fine
- [OpenShift](https://www.openshift.com/) is a great alternative
- [Pivotal](http://run.pivotal.io/) seems to be alright
- [Google App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/) and [Amazon Elastic Beanstalk](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/Welcome.html) are most likely overkill

#### Workflow

This is a very broad subject. Everyone has their own ways of doing things. At a minimum I would get familiar with the following tools or concepts:

1. [npm](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/what-is-npm) (default package manager)

   1. alternative: [yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/) (faster, shinier)
2. [eslint](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/getting-started) (linter for javascript, indispensable)
3. [Gitflow](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow) (sane way to manage your git repo)
4. [Semver](http://semver.org/) (what is semantic versioning)
5. [Unit Testing with Tape](https://hackernoon.com/unit-testing-node-js-38cf2b7e1a41) (it's 2017, you need tests)

   1. alternative: [Mocha](https://mochajs.org/) (more functionalities, some you don't need)
6. [Airbnb Style Guide](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript) (a decent baseline for style)

   1. alternative: [Google Style Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/jsguide.html) (I use this one)

There is also this [overwhelming but great list](https://github.com/sindresorhus/awesome-nodejs), which is a bit too much but should list anything else you might need

Finally, if you want to work more with Express, I would suggest going through this MDN series [Express Web Framework](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Express_Nodejs). Once that is done, I would installing the [Express App Generator](https://github.com/expressjs/generator), create a test app and looking at the structure of files and folders